# Is there a way to make SELECT that fails not throw inside a TRY/CATCH?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProc
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  BEGIN TRY
    ...
    DECLARE @Id INT;

    -- I don't want the following line to throw and abort processing. 
    -- I just want @Id to remain NULL. I can add a nested TRY/CATCH, but is there
    -- a better way?
    SET @Id=(SELECT Id FROM MyTable WHERE ...); 
    ...
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    ...
  END CATCH;
END;
```

Update: Just to clarify, if multiple rows are returned, I want @Id to stay NULL.

Comment: What type of error are you expecting on that select? Can you just avoid the expected error with a top 1? If there are no matches the @ID will remain null.

Comment: I want @Id to stay NULL if there are multiple Ids returned, as per Jose's 2nd answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will do something like this to avoid multiple rows errors:

```
SELECT top 1 @Id = Id FROM MyTable WHERE ...
```

or this

```
SELECT @Id = Id FROM MyTable WHERE ...
if @@rowcount > 1
   set @id = null
```

This last piece will set the @Id to null when there were multiple rows.

Comment: But it sounds like that if there are multiple rows, the OP wants it to be null, not just have one of the values

Comment: I think the second query is what the OP is looking for.  The first one doesn't meet his requirement "I just want @Id to remain NULL. "

Comment: Jose, +1 yours is easier to understand which is usually more important!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select @id = (select max(id) from MyTable Where <YOUR CONDITION> Having count(1) = 1)
```

This will return a single row, or no rows if there are multiple matching.

Comment: I think Ben's solution is pretty elegant and will perform similar to the if @@rowcount.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this would not throw:

```
SELECT @Id = Id FROM MyTable WHERE ...
```

Comment: but that will just store the last value, which i do not think is what the OP wants

Comment: @RGI - what are you talking about? @ Stefan H - store the last value?

Comment: @RGI the OP post would throw an error if the subquery returned more than one result, this one would not

Comment: I think the OP is worried about their query returning multiple results, therefore throwing an error with the code that they have.  If that was the case, your sql would just store the last value, and not let the OP know that multiple results were returned (which is when they want it to be null)

Comment: I see, I didn't understand that was what he wanted (he didn't state it)

Comment: I am really just guessing what the OP wants since they did not explain it very well, but it seems to make the most sense to me.